# Carbon less than equals returns false even though the date and times are the same

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, debugging, php-carbon

I am working on a website and I am writing some tests for it - testing if some records were created with the correct data and if the records are created after the start of the test by comparing the `created_at` date with the one I generate at the start of the test. Initially, I was using `lt` (less than method) rather than `lte` (less than or equals method on carbon) which I thought was causing the problem but then I switched to `lte` and the problem persisted. I've used `xdebug` to debug the problem but, strangely, in my IDE it shows the datetime strings to be exactly the same yet it returns false. Note that the majority of the cases it returns `true` and it works but every now and then it doesn't. Also, note this a Laravel app running `PHP 8.0`.

Here is the code where the magic happens, look around line 55 (note it has some debugging code to make it more understandable):

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Tests;

use App\Models\Devices\Device;
use App\Actions\Common;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Exception;

class DatabaseRecords {
    /**
     * Tests if records in the db match the one in $data,
     * as well as if records in db have been created
     * after the start of the test.
     */
    public static function testRecords($test, $data, $deviceId, $type = 'mqtt')
    {
        $device = Device::findOrFail($deviceId);

        foreach ($data as $sensorType => $items) {
            $sensors = $device->sensors()->where('type', $sensorType)->where('channel', $items['channel'])->get();

            if ($sensors->count() > 1) {
                throw new Exception('More than one sensor of the same type and channel.');
            }

            $sensor = $sensors->first();
            $lastRecords = $sensor->getLastFewDataRecords();

            if (Common::isMultiValueSensor($sensor->type)) {
                foreach ($items['data'] as $item) {
                    foreach ($lastRecords as $record) {
                        if ($item->stype === $record['stype']) {
                            $test->assertEquals($item->value, $record['value']);

                            $test->assertTrue($test->startTime->lte(new Carbon($record['created_at'])));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if ($type === 'mqtt') {
                    $value = $items['data'][0]->value;
                } else {
                    $value = $items['data'];
                }
                
                $test->assertEquals($value, $lastRecords[0]['value']);

                $startTimeString = $test->startTime->toDateTimeString();
                $recordCreatedTimeString = $lastRecords[0]['created_at'];

                $recordCreatedCarbon = Carbon::parse($recordCreatedTimeString);

                if (! $test->startTime->lte($recordCreatedCarbon)) {
                    $test2 = $recordCreatedCarbon->toDateTimeString();
                    echo 'test';
                }

                $test->assertTrue($test->startTime->lte(Carbon::parse($recordCreatedTimeString)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is a screenshot of my IDE while debugging it:

I've tried googling for `Carbon` bugs but found nothing.

[image]

Comment: Interesting find. Can't speak to that behaviour, I typically don't use the `->lte()` (or other) methods, but prefer the operators `<=`, etc. Or, instead of checking `if(!$a->lte($b))`, you check the inverse `if($a->gt($b))` or `if($a > $b)`, etc. Those seem to behave slightly differently too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoMoO.png

Comment: Nope, they are not different, the issue in your screenshot is the operator precedence.

`!$a < $b` is implicitly `(!$a) < $b`

You need: `!($a < $b)` then you get the same as `->lte()` which actually also use a simple comparison + parsing if argument is a string.

Comment: I can only see that the string representations of dates look the same. However that doesn't say anything about timezones or milliseconds that may exist when the dates are instantiated.

Comment: @apokryfos well afaik Carbon automatically picks up the timezone from Laravel. And none of the strings have milliseconds. Plus why does it work most of the time?

Comment: Might be helpful (to the question and to you) if you expanded the carbon objects in the case where it fails to inspect what they actually contain

Comment: Compared the timestamps from both Caron instances and they are still the same but compared the milliseconds and the first Carbon's milliseconds are more which I assume is causing the problem but how do I get rid of the milliseconds in a good way? @apokryfos

Comment: I have a solution for now but it is not very elegant, this: Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - gets rid of the milliseconds in the first date and it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in the milliseconds as @apokryfos suggested. Just make sure the `Carbon` instances don't have milliseconds if you are not using them. One way to do that is by initializing `Carbon` this way:

```
Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```